# Cucumber inconsistency between running all scenarios and running a single one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, bdd, capybara

I'm BDD testing my application with Capybara and I'm getting all sorts of errors when running all scenarios. But when I run some of that failing scenarios I don't receive any errors.

Example:

`bundle exec cucumber features`

returns

```
Failing Scenarios:

features/dashboard/new_listing.feature:16 # Scenario: Happy Path`
```

And when I run

`bundle exec cucumber features/dashboard/new_listing.feature:16 -r features`

I get:

`1 scenario (1 passed)`

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: This will be very difficult to diagnose without seeing your entire codebase.  http://ryanbigg.com/2011/10/that-one-test/ may be of some use to you.

Comment: Do your cucumber change the state of the database. Are you using the database_cleaner gem. https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner

Comment: Yes, it does change the state of DB, and I'm already using database_cleaner